# Recently any new Maven project I create in Eclipse will have "[workspace master]" as part of the title in the package explorer view

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, testing

Recently any new Java project I create in Eclipse will have "[workspace master]" as part of the title in the package explorer view. I have not been able to find any help articles stating what this is and how to get rid of

Comment: I think that may be from the GIT repository? add a capture :)

Comment: Those are usually from whichever source control system you are using (Git, ...). What is shown can be configured in the Preference pages for the SCS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the branch you are on the GIT repository, also you could have a number with the number of commits ahead of master (not in your case cause you are already on [workspace master])